# FULLY stop an antivirus from running

Tags: windows, anti-virus, avast

I would like a way to **fully** stop Avast or any antivirus from running. 
I don't want to uninstall Avast or disable the Shields I want to be able to look in task manager and not see Avast running as a process.

Please could someone tell me a way to do this.

Comment: Usually uninstall is the only way to completely stop them. Their job includes to  prevent being disabled.

Comment: You can't. If you really don't want to see it in task manager then [uninstall it](http://www.getavast.net/downloads/uninstall-utility/)

Comment: Additionally, even uninstall will not restore quarantined items. If the AV has eaten some essential component, then uninstalling that app & reinstalling [sometimes to a new non-default folder is required], then whitelisting before first run is the only way to get functionality back.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible.  If it was then malware could disable AV software which would make them useless

Comment: Common guys, I said in my post I don't want to uninstall. Also, can a program really completely prevent windows from stopping it?

Comment: What you want cannot be done. Antivirus apps are quite keen that it cannot be done, so do a lot to prevent it. If you don't want to uninstall, then you have to put up with the consequences.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Avast but the following rules would apply, having disabled any Tamper Protection.  1. Run services.msc, stop/disable any Avast services.  I assume they start "Avast".  2. I assume there is some auto-run process that is responsible for a tray icon, in which case you can probably disable that with Autoruns/msconfig but if you're only looking to disable this on a per session basis you should be able to terminate the process.  Is the aim here to disable Avast while you play a game to minimise system resources? Maybe a batch file?

Comment: How would one disable Tamper Protection?

Comment: On my Comodo antivirus I do the following, using CCleaner app disable its entry in Auto Start with Windows and most importantly Disable the Comodo Service in Administrative Tools--> Services. (I just mark it as Disabled, it does not actually immediately) Only upon subsequent restart, Comodo completely stops. Undo the things to get it back again. However I do not know how Avast works.

Comment: I've just installed Avast. An option called self defense can be disabled - https://imgur.com/a/Fpvzb Once off you can kill the tray process for example `taskkill /F /IM avastui.exe` You can stop the service `sc stop avast! antivirus`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I want to be able to look in task manager and not see Avast running as a process.

Do the following at your own risk:

1. Open the Avast User interface
2. Click on "Settings"
3. Uncheck "Enable Avast self-defence module"

   [image]
4. Click "OK"
5. Click "Yes" on the warning dialog (no screen capture is possible for this).
6. Close the Avast User interface
7. Open a `cmd` shell
8. Run the following command

   ```
   taskkill /F /IM avastui.exe
   SUCCESS: The process "AvastUI.exe" with PID 5928 has been terminated.
   ```
9. Start > Run >  Services
10. Right click "Avast Antivirus" and select "Stop"

    [image]

Thanks to [HelpingHand](https://superuser.com/users/682835/helpinghand) for his comment that led to this answer.

Comment: The setting is under `Menu > Settings > General > Troubleshooting > Enable Self-Defense` now